# Await delay ruined typewriter effect c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I'm making an application in which I want to add a cool looking typewriter effect without having the UI freezing with thread.sleep.

So I was just searching around for a solution to find the async thing which I featured in the class and everything just broke but I do not understand why.
It was working perfect before but the ui froze now it doesn't but the text is random characters

old (working but freezes ui):

```
    private bool Write(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            Console.AppendText(c.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        Console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        return true;
    }
```

new (weird chars does not freeze ui):

```
    private async void Write(string text){
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            Console.AppendText(c.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(5);
        }
        Console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

I was hoping the new code would fix the ui freezing which it did but the text is litterally unreadable..
here is a result before and after:

before (using old code with ui freeze):

```
ModuleRemover is aan het kijken voor updates.
ModuleRemover is al de laatste versie! (versie 2.4)
```

after:

```
MMododuuleleReRemomvoveerr i is s aaanl  hdeet l kaaitjsketen  vveoorsr iuep! d(atveesrs.
ie 2.4)
```

Comment: Looks like your two lines are merged together, into some sort of *double-dutch*

Comment: For the next time (about code formatting): 1) your code must be separated from the body of your text by a double "carriage return" at the top and the bottom, and 2) every line of your code must be indented at least 4 spaces

Comment: I have never seen `Console.AppendText`, is that in the `System.Console` namespace?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yeah now you said it it actually does..

Comment: How are you calling `Write`?

Comment: No, it's a multiline textbox named Console haha, I named it like that so it would be easier to remember..

Comment: Write("ModuleRemover is aan het kijken voor updates.");

Comment: and Write("ModuleRemover is al de laatste versie! (versie " + newver + ")");

Comment: That's the problem, you are calling `Write` twice, so they run in parallel. You have to wait until the first one finishes

Comment: hmmm so I could possibly add a bool which goes true when a sentence is finished then does the next one or something?

Comment: Right, when you made `Write` `async`, it stopped being synchronous (go figure).  you need to `await` them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With synchronous loop you block any other activity till your code finishes "typing". As result second call to `Write` will have to wait and output will not mix with output of first one.

Presumably with `async` version you start both `Write` calls at the same time and let them run in parallel - indeed they'll type characters at the same time.

Fix: make `Write` return `Task`

```
private async Task Write(string text) …
```

and `await` first call before making the second one (you may need to make method calling `Write` to be async too:

```
await Write("First one");
await Write("Second one");
```

Comment: this would mean I would have to change all of the functions that call ```Write();``` to async right?

Comment: @DaniëlDeJong yes (as I've already commented in the answer "you may need to make method calling Write to be async too")

Answer (score 0):

The reason for UI freezing is likely because you're using the thread of the UI. This will freeze it.

```
private bool Write(string text)
{
    var t;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        t = Task.Run(() => Console.AppendText(c.ToString());
        t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
    }
    t = Task.Run(() => Console.AppendText(Console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine));
    t.Wait(); // wait for completion.
    return true;
}
```